# Android SDK Manager Install Specific Version of NDK Bundle

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to install NDK 15c and I can't seem to figure out how to tell sdkmanager the version. If I run

```
sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
```

I will get the latest which I don't want.

I've tried different combinations but nothing works:

```
sdkmanager "ndk-bundle;15c"

sdkmanager "ndk-bundle;15.2.4203891"

sdkmanager "ndk-bundle;15.2"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just download the android-NDK from their archives and integrate it with your android studio. You can download android-NDK 15 from the given URL:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

To connect it with android studio, extract it into your drive and in android studio, go to File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> NDK Path (Put extracted path here)

Comment: Note that the path of the folder where the NDK gets extracted should not contain white spaces and should not reside in the program folder of Android Studio.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Gradle plugin 3.5 or later (in beta at time of writing, but will be out soon), add the following to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ndkVersion "19.2.5345600" // NDK r19c
}
```

If you're using an older Gradle plugin, you can download old NDK releases from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases and point `ndk.dir` in your `local.properties` file at that instead.

Comment: Looks like only r20 really supports the automatic downloading of the NDK package. Downloading of r19c does not work: No version of NDK matched the requested version 19.2.5345600. Versions available locally: 20.0.5594570

Comment: That's a bug. Please file an Android Studio bug by following https://b.android.com

Comment: For anyone that reads this in the future, a bug was filed here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132876707. However, I am seeing this still broken in r21, so I filed another bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143630825

Answer (score 15):

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#command-line):

> 1. Use the [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) tool to view versions of CMake and NDK packages
>      that are available:
>
>    ```
>    sdkmanager --list
>    ```
> 2. Pass the sdkmanager the strings for the packages that you want to
>      install. For example, to install CMake and the NDK, use the following
>      syntax:
>
>    ```
>    sdkmanager --install
>      "ndk;major.minor.build"
>      "cmake;major.minor.micro.build"
>    ```

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: this answer saved my life :), since I have just access to command line in remote server

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I resolved it through the SDK manager under SDK Tools, click `Show Package Details` and then scroll under NDK (Side by side) and tick and apply the version you need. See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download previous versions of NDK in Android Studio by clicking-
Tools > SDK Manager.
SDK Tools
Select the Show Package Details checkbox.
NDK (Side by side) checkbox

choose the version you want to download

This is clearly explained in the following Url-

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#apply-specific-version