# How to rebuild OpenCv with c++_static?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

I am new to opencv in android. I imported the opencv module 3.4.2 successfully.
In application.mk

```
APP_STL:=gnustl_static
```

When I tried to build the application, I got NDK build error that 'gnustl_static' is no longer supported. I changed the above line in application.mk to

`APP_STL:=c++_static`
as suggested by android studio.

The build was successful and I ran the project successfully. Now I tried to implement the face detection with opencv as like as opencv samples 'face-detection'. I got the error this time :

```
E:/MyOpenDetections/app/src/main/jni/com_sar_pahc_DetectionBasedTracker.cpp:37: error: undefined reference to 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::_InputArray const&, std::__ndk1::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::__ndk1::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>)'
```

I searched about this and got some suggestions that I have to change the APP_STL to 'gnustl_static' from 'c++_static' but when I do this the NDK stops the build and shows that it is not supported now.

I got some hint from Alex Cohn that I have to rebuild the Opencv with c++_static
[OpenCV - undefined reference to 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale() after NDK update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315422/opencv-undefined-reference-to-cvcascadeclassifierdetectmultiscale-after)

But I have no idea of doing that.
Please help

Comment: Another solution here would be to [download an older version of the NDK and associate it with your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52504296/5132744).

Answer (score 1):

You can try solution from opencv bugtracker ([source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8742#issuecomment-385553011)):

> cmake -GNinja -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=ON
>   -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DWITH_IPP=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
>   -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static" -DANDROID_ABI=x86 -DANDROID_SDK_TARGET=18 ../opencv

Followed by

> make && make install

Comment: in windows > inside opencv sdk folder > ran the above command >
CMake Error: The source directory "E:/OpenCV-android-sdk" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: OpenCV-android-sdk is the output of this command. You need to run the script using opencv source code https://github.com/opencv/opencv